# How to read large images as numpy.memmap objects

Tags: python, image, numpy

How can one read large images as **`numpy.memmap`** objects so it is possible to manipulate their pixels and save them back? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what did you try? how big are your images? what file format? etc. We cant help much if you do not give more specifics

Comment: From the documentation: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html 

You will need to know how far into the file the image data starts (`offset`), what data type each pixel is (`dtype`) and the shape of the image (`image`). The object returned can be manipulated like a normal Numpy array.

Comment: For the BMP format for example you could refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing further deatils, I would use [scipy.misc.imread](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/misc.html). Scipy uses [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open), which in turn uses [mmap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html):

```py
>>> from scipy import misc
>>> pix_array = misc.imread('image_fname') # read only
>>> type(pix_array)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> # manipulate pix_array to get `altered_pix_array`
>>> misc.imsave('altered_image_fname', altered_pix_array)
```

If `scipy.misc.imread` does not work right out of the box, try `pip install pillow` to install/reinstall [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open) properly. GL+HF